# PHP MySQL Database Column Referencing

Tags: php, mysql, database

sorry for bothering you again but I'm really stuck!

How would it be possible to do an if statement referencing wherever or not data was from a certain column or to strip the last number in a column's name and reference it that way?

Basically I have an musicians database, where a person from the PEOPLE table is linked via ID to instruments in the INSTRUMENTS table, I have an e-mail search function that I need to send out the relative data to the relative instruments. So if someone plays guitar as their 2nd instrument and someone else plays it as their 5th I need the relevant grade, standard and comments to get sent with them in the e-mail function.

I want to get the comments[i] , grade[i], standard[i] of the matching instrument[i]

My tables layout: ( I know it isn';t very efficient and I will look into DB normalization in the future!)

---

TABLE:**INSTRUMENTS**

COLUMNS:

```
 id   instrument1   grade2  standard3   comments4   
      instrument2   grade2  standard2   comments2   
      instrument3   grade3  standard3   comments3   
      instrument4   grade4  standard4   comments4   
      instrument5   grade5  standard5   comments5
```

TABLE: **PEOPLE**

COLUMNS:

```
id  first  last  snumber  course  email  graduate  inumber
```

---

EDIT:

> ```
>       while($getresults = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
> ```

```
      $peoplequery = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = {$getresults [id]}";
      $peopleresults = @mysql_query($peoplequery);
      $getpeopleresults = mysql_fetch_assoc($peopleresults);

 //add the details returned by the database to the table:


      $table .= "  
      <td><p>{$getpeopleresults [first]} {$getpeopleresults [last]}</p></td>
      <td><p>{$getpeopleresults [email]}</p></td>
      <td><p>{$getpeopleresults [course]}</p></td>
      <td><p>{$getresults [grade]}</p></td>
      <td><p>{$getresults [standard]}</p></td>
      <td><p>{$getresults [comments]}</p></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan=8><hr size=1 color=gray></td></tr>
      }

  ";

}
```

Comment: You are right: it'll be easier to fix the DB design once the app is finished :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Caleb
But still you wanna be with this database design, you can do like this, this is most in-efficient way because of your DB structure.

I have not tested this, so there might be some syntax errors.

```
$selQuery = "select * from instruments LEFT JOIN people ON instruments.id=people.id where instrument1 like 'guitar' OR instrument2 like 'guitar' OR instrument3 like 'guitar' OR instrument4 like 'guitar' OR instrument5 like 'guitar'";

$resQuery = mysql_query($selQuery)

$peoples = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resQuery))
{
   for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++ )
   {
       if(strtolower($row['instrument'.$i]) == strtolower('Guitar'))
       {
            $people = array();
            $people['id'] = $row['id'];
            $people['first'] = $row['first'];
            $people['email'] = $row['email'];
            $people['instrument'] = $row['instrument'.$i];
            $people['grade'] = $row['grade'.$i];
            $people['standard'] = $row['standard'.$i];
            $people['comments'] = $row['comments'.$i];
            array_push($peoples , $people);
            break;
       }
   }
}
```

ok I have reviewed ur code,

make changes as below

```
//Find instruments searched for:

$query = "SELECT * from instruments where '$search' in (instrument , instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5)";

$result = @mysql_query($query);

//Start building the table:
    $table = "<th><p><b>You searched for $search</b></p></th>
        <table>
        <th> <p><b>Name </b></p></th>

    <th> <p><b>Email </b></p> </th>

    <th> <p><b>Course </b></p></th>

    <th> <p><b>Grade </b></p></th>

    <th> <p><b>Standard </b></p></th>

    <th> <p><b>Comments</b></p>

</th></tr>";


    $peoples = array();
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

           if(strtolower($row['instrument']) == strtolower($search))
       {
            $people = array();
            $people['id'] = $row['id'];
            $people['instrument'] = $row['instrument'.$i];
            $people['grade'] = $row['grade'.$i];
            $people['standard'] = $row['standard'.$i];
            $people['comments'] = $row['comments'.$i];
            array_push($peoples , $people);
            continue;
       }

   for($i = 2; $i<= 5; $i++ )
   {
       if(strtolower($row['instrument'.$i]) == strtolower($search))
       {
            $people = array();
                $people['id'] = $row['id'];
                $people['instrument'] = $row['instrument'.$i];
                $people['grade'] = $row['grade'.$i];
                $people['standard'] = $row['standard'.$i];
                $people['comments'] = $row['comments'.$i];
                array_push($peoples , $people);
                break;
           }
       }

 }

       foreach($peoples as $people)
       {
          $peoplequery = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = '".$people[id]."'";

          $peopleresults = @mysql_query($peoplequery);

          $getpeopleresults = mysql_fetch_assoc($peopleresults);



  //add the details returned by the database to the table:





          $table .= " 

          <td><p>{$getpeopleresults[first]} {$getpeopleresults[last]}</p></td>

          <td><p>{$getpeopleresults[email]}</p></td>

          <td><p>{$getpeopleresults[course]}</p></td>

                  <td><p>{$people[grade]}</p></td>

          <td><p>{$people[standard]}</p></td>

          <td><p>{$people[comments]}</p></td></tr>

                  <tr><td colspan=8><hr size=1 color=gray></td></tr>

                  }



          ";

}
```

Comment: Cool - currently I just have **'$query = "SELECT * FROM instruments WHERE '$search' IN (instrument , instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5";

 $result = @mysql_query($query);**'    -how could I adapt this to your code?

Comment: just replace $selQuery with this "SELECT * from instruments left join people on instruments.id = people.id where '$search' in (instrument1 , instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5" $result = @mysql_query($query); this might work. best of luck.

Comment: @Maulik Getting close I can feel it, please check the edit of my question, this I think is the only bit I now need to edit, this is the bit of code that the e-mail function uses. What do I need to change here?

Comment: @toby have u tried my whole code? $peoples array might be giving you whatever you want. actually I didn't get anything from your updated question, Please add some more code or try whatever I had given in my code

Comment: @Maulik - here is my full code http://pastebin.ca/2045921 - I tried your code but the E-mail does not send any data now

Comment: @Toby try now, I have updated answer. check for any syntax error

Comment: @Maulik - I checked Syntax, there was a 1 missing from instrument, it works BEAUTIFULLY. THANK YOU!!! :)

Comment: @Toby If your field name was 'instrument1' then just change this code for($i = 1 ; $i <= 5 ; $i++) in the code , before that it was $i = 2;

Comment: @Maulik Yes I figured that one :) Thank you once more!

Answer (score 1):

You are feeling really stuck because you're trying to squash a square peg in a round hole. This would be really easy if you used a table layout that allowed you to use your DB the way DBs were intended to function.

The only hack that will work for now is to write crazy long SQL statements meticulously trying every possibility or concatenating all the fields and looking for partial matches. Please don't do that. Spend some time to redesign your table layout so you can use joins and query using standard SQL practices.

Comment: Cool, OK I'll try and start again then - Thanks.

Comment: From the looks of things, you're going to want separate tables for instruments, grades, standards and comments, then a link those into people with a many-to-one key. It's not clear from your question exactly what the layout should be or what is keyed to what, but unique items (such as people, or instument types) should have unique ids, then they should be linked with another table of id-id pairs. Grades and comments might not need linking tables if each comment or grade is individual to a person, just having that person as a foreign-key column in those tables is enough to make a link.